# Removing everything between two strings regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following:

```
<span class="hello" id="something somemore"> blah blah blah </span>
```

My regex is not my strongest ability, would appreciate is someone could help me in javascript regex.

I would like to remove everything/anything and including from `<span` to `>` and then finally just remove the `</span>`.

I am using `.replace(myregexhere, "");` to replace other items but I am struggling to do the above.

Also if there are easier or better alternatives let me know.

Comment: why not just remove the element itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to use regex replace, try this:

```
var newstring = oldstring.replace(/<span[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/span>/, "$1");
```

Note that this doesn't work if any html tags are in between `<span>` and `</span>`. If you have html tags there then please use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11850294/1337398) instead.

Comment: Replace `([^<]*)` with `(.*)`, and add `^` and `$` anchors to the ends.  Then the `*`'s greedy matching will ensure the regex still works even if the `<span>` contains markup.

Comment: @Deestan I assumed that no markup is in the `<span></span>` block. Also, why are `^` and `$` required in case I wanted to do greedy matching?

Comment: They aren't really required for the greedy matching, that was just me being a bit thick.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like:

```
~<span.+?>~
```

and

```
~</span>~
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) instead :

```
var something = $('#something').text();
$('#something').replaceWith(something);
```

Comment: I am doing this but using `.html()` and then replacing it after manipulation. My manipulation is what requires me to remove the spans.

Answer (score -1):

use jQuery:

```
$('span').remove();
```

or for each span with class "hello":

```
$('span .hello').remove();
```

or for each element with id "something somemore",

```
$("#something somemore").remove();
```

Comment: your jQuery is incorrect and you aren't answering the question.